Prove that $a=bc$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$


Given that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$a^2=b^3+ab$$ and $$c^3=a+b+c$$ Then Prove that $a=bc$


My effort:
Since $$c^3-c=a+b \Rightarrow 6 | (a+b)$$ So both $a$ and $b$ are even. Because if both $a$ and $b$ are odd, $b^3+ab$ is even and is a contradiction.
EDIT: Also we can now take $a=2x, b=2y$. Since $a+b$ is a multiple of $6$, it means $x+y$ must be a multiple of $3$.
Any help from here?

Please edit for context.  Why do you believe this might be true?  Have you found many solutions $(a,b,c)$ to the pair of equations?  How far have you searched or have you found an infinite family of solutions? Is there any particular reason to look at this Diophantine system?  You tag "contest-math"...is this from a contest?  If so, please provide a link or reference.

$$a=\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4b^3}}2=b\cdot\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4b}}2.$$

We will first prove that the first equality implies that $b \mid a$. Indeed, assume not, then there must be a prime $p$ and a nonnegative integer $n$ such that \begin{align} \begin{cases}p^n \mid a,b \\ p^{n+1} \nmid a \\ p^{n+1} \mid b \end{cases}. \end{align} In particular, we can check that $p^{2n+1} \nmid a^2$ but $p^{2n+1} \mid b^3 +ab$, which is a contradiction as $a^2 = b^3+ab$.
Let $a = bk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $a^2=b^3+ab$ implies $b = k^2-k$, which also implies that $a =k^3-k^2$. Thus
$$c^3-c = a+b = k^3-k \Rightarrow c = k.$$
Hence $a = k^3-k^2 = (k^2-k)k = bc$ as desired.
